# User Registration Error on CE 1.9.3.0

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a site that we recently upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9 however when trying to register as a new customer I get the error message that the passwords must match. I have checked each of the files and its not a form key issue. I have also checked the sessions in Magento Admin and it all looks okay to me.

Any idea of what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.9.1.0, the code that sets the password confirmation in `_getCustomerErrors` method in the customer controller has changed from:

```
$customer->setConfirmation($request->getPost('confirmation'));
```

To:

```
$customer->setPasswordConfirmation($request->getPost('confirmation'));
```

I suggest you double check if you don't have a custom module that overrides that method or deals with login which could be the issue.

Also, I assume you flush the cache and recompile if you're using compilation.

Comment: Do you know where I would find that controller? As I will try that, as I also suspect it could be the hash in the database. I have tried flushing the cache and reindex.